# How do I check if a class is in included in the manifest classpath?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I have some jars being referenced by classpath JVM arg (-cp) and other referenced by a pathing jar that includes additional jars via a Manifest file.

At runtime, how can I check the presence of a class  that scans the -cp jars as well as those referenced by the pathing jar? This is required for some initialization task that scans classes for a particular annotation.

Comment: The same way you would check for any class in the classpath:  `Class.forName("com.example.SomeClassOfInterest")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.some.Class");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // Specified class not found
}
```

Note, from the `Class.forName` documentation:

> A call to `forName("X")` causes the class named `X` to be initialized.